# Applying CSS to HTML5 Fullscreen API?

Tags: html, css

I am trying [this example](http://johndyer.name/lab/fullscreenapi/) for the full-screen API. Is it possible to apply CSS to the full screen element (eg. `"#box"`)? For example I want to display some text in the full-screen, so I would like to have its width 80% of the screen and add some padding there.
Also, is it possible to style an element only when it is in the full-screen mode? Thanks.
I have tried this:

```
#box:-webkit-full-screen {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background: #FFFFFF !important;
  }
  #box:-moz-full-screen {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background: #FFFFFF !important;
  }
```

This works on chrome, but Firefox ignores the width.

Comment: can you make a jsFiddle of your question? This will help us determine, what exactly is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

While you handle toggling on and off fullscreen mode, you can add and remove some class for body or html element and write your css for fullscreen mode in context of this class.